# What is the equivalent parse query for this sql query in IOS

Tags: ios, join, parse-platform

I have three Parse classes in my IOS app: User, Pin, and Visit. A Pin represents a place on a map and a Visit represents a User who has visited that Pin. Naturally there are many Visits that point to the same Pin. Pin is a PFGeoPoint and Visit is comprised of two strings, the objectId of the particular Pin (pinId) and the objectId of the User who visited that pin (userId).

I right now have a query that finds all nearby Pins to the device. However, I want to also know if the user has also visited this Pin before. I've looked through the Parse Dev Docs but can't find the answer. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For Javascript, it would be something like this:

```
var listOfPins = ["23j208f", "23948fs", "skdf82fh"]; // objectIDs of nearby Pins
var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
var Visit = Parse.Object.extend("Visit");
var query = new Parse.Query(Visit);
query.equalTo("userId", currentUser.id);
query.containedIn("pinId", listOfPins);

query.find({
    success: function(results) {
        if (results.length > 0) {
            // do something with the visits
        }
    }
});
```

For iOS:

```
NSArray *listOfPins = @["34d2342d", "2342d34", "234sdf234"];
PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Visit"];
[query whereKey:@"userId" equalTo:currentUser.objectId];
[query whereKey:@"pinId" containedIn:listOfPins];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
{
    for (PFObject *visit in objects)
    {
        // do something with the visits
    }
}];
```

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned this, I'm working on an IOS app.

Comment: Alright then, I've added iOS code. I would recommend getting comfortable with Javascript if you're using Parse though, since the cloud code features they provide are useful

Comment: Is there any way to do this in one query? As in grab the list of pins and run the above query?

Comment: If you only want to retrieve pins that the user has visited, you could use [a relational query](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries-relational/iOS). It sounds like you want two separate groups of objects, though - a list of all nearby pins, and a list of all nearby pins that the user has visited. In this case I believe you need two queries, although you could write a custom cloud function to return both lists at once.

Comment: No I want one list of all nearby pins with a field specifying whether a user has been there before.